# Question on why this differential equation is solved like this.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is what it says in my notebook how the following differential equations are solved:
$$F(t,x,x',x'',...x^{(n)})=0$$ such that: $$F(t,lx,lx',lx'',...lx^{(n)})=l^kF(t,x,x',x'',...x^{(n)})$$ then the substitution $x'=xz(t)$ is brought in.

concrete example: $$t^2xx''=x^2-2txx'-+t^2x'^2$$ then $x'=xz(t)$ again the substitution.

What I can;t seem to see is how is this concrete differential equation the same as the one in the definition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, $$F(t,x,x',x'')=t^2xx''-x^2+2txx'+-t^2x'^2$$
F is homogeneous of degree two because, if you multiply each of $x$, $x'$ and $x''$ by $l$, $F$ is multiplied by $l^2$.

Comment: Can you help out with this one: $x'=f(ax+bt+c)$ is solved as $z(t)=ax+bt+c$ then in $x'={r^2 \over (t+x)^2}; z(t)=t+x$ but here we have $x$ in the denominator and to the second degree. How is this explained ??

Comment: In the first one, $dz/dt=adx/dt+b=af(z)+b$, which is separable.  Again, in the second one, $dz/dt=1+dx/dt=1+r^2/z^2$.  They are two ways to make $t$ disappear.  The result is separable, which can be solved.

Comment: And I don't see how $x'= \sqrt{t^2-x^2}+ x$ is homogeneous . Can you help out with these ?

Comment: I don't think it is.

Comment: It seems like this equation : $y(y - xy') = \sqrt{x^4 + y^4}$ also can be solved with the substitution y=tx but is not homogeounous ?